# How to get the satellite count from the fused location api?

Tags: android, gps, satellite, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am using GoogleApiClient to request location update. I am getting the latitude, longitude, speed and other information. Along with this I want to get the satellite count also. How can I achieve this?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code to get the satellite count in use and in view

```
gpsStatus = locationManager.getGpsStatus (gpsStatus);
        Iterable<GpsSatellite> satellites = gpsStatus.getSatellites ();
        int sattInView = 0;
        int sattInUse = 0;
        if (satellites != null) {
            for (GpsSatellite gpsSatellite : satellites) {
                sattInView++;
                if (gpsSatellite.usedInFix ()) {
                    sattInUse++;
                }
            }
        }
        inView = String.valueOf (sattInView);
        inUse = String.valueOf (sattInUse);
```

Comment: I have not used the location manager API. I have used the GoogleApiClient API. This class not having a method called getGpsStatus (gpsStatus);

Comment: As you are using FusedAPI which uses either your nearest cell tower or GPS satellite to get a fix on your location, I am afraid it won't be possible to the best of my knowledge..

Comment: Yes I have used FusedAPI.